# Mounting a parameter on the root url crashes resource location wicket

Tags: wicket-6

in my wicket application settings I wish to mount a username parameter on the root like

mountPage (Profile.class, "/${username}") similar to how twitter maps the usernames to its accounts. In wicket this seems to crash the resource location algorithm. In the sense that all css, js files now load with 404.

Is there a work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to martin-g. Override the MountMapper with set the url segments to 1 so it doesn't map to other resources.

```
 public class UsernameMountUrlMapper extends MountedMapper {

    public UsernameMountUrlMapper(String mountPath,
         Class<? extends IRequestablePage> pageClass) {
       super(mountPath, pageClass);
  }

  @Override
  protected boolean urlStartsWithMountedSegments(Url url) {
      return url.getSegments().size() == 1 &&      !url.getPath().equals("favicon.ico") && !url.getPath().equals("oops") && !url.getPath().equals("Index");
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The code should look like: `mountPage (Profile.class, "/${username}")`. Note the **$** that I've added. This means the named path parameter is mandatory.

Please give more details about the problem if this doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: I only missed the dollar here. It's in my code. It seems the / mountpoint conflicts with the /${username}.

Comment: Resources located with <wicket:link> now show ../resource/com.app.prototype.web.Authenticated/bootstrap.min-ver-1428321141752.css. When it used to be ./wicket/resource/com.app.prototype.web.Authenticated/bootstrap.min-ver-1428321141752.css

Comment: If they clash then you can use the home page as an entry point. If there is parameters.get(0) then this is the username. IF there is no such parameter then show the generic page.